# Find an ID number in an SQL table that isn't listed in an array of numbers

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have a table that looks like the following;

```
id     header
1      fruit
4      header_example
9      test
13     money
```

I then have an array that *used* to contain each of the id's, but I remove one. I now for example, have an array that looks like this:

```
array = [1, 9, 13]
```

How would I look at that array, and determine that the row with id=4 should be deleted?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you hook the removal of the array element and simply remember which ID you pulled out?  The listed solutions work just fine, but become cumbersome with thousands of IDs and may exceed "value list" limits with tens of thousands of IDs.

Comment: @pilcrow in my case I'll only ever have 4 array elements to look at.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the MySQL side, you could just run this, using php to output the array contents into the IN clause:

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE id NOT IN ( <array contents> )
```

On the PHP side, you could generate the appropriate contents:

```
' . implode(', ', $arr) . '
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$arr = array(1, 9, 11);
$query = 'DELETE FROM tbl WHERE id NOT IN (' . implode(', ', $arr) . ')';
mysql_query($query);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$sql = 'DELETE FROM table WHERE id not in ('.implode(',', $array).')';
```